# background process is always Stopped

Tags: linux, unix, process

I am executing a background process with the following command:

```
{ geth | node | whatever } &
```

When I check the `jobs` the status of this process is always `Stopped`.

If I add this command to a .sh file and I execute it the same way, it also happens.

Any idea why it is happening or any other solution to make background processes using just command lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running with nohup. You can analyse the nohup.out log if it still stops.

```
nohup script.sh
```

Comment: Also consider adding & at the end: `nohup script.sh &`